# how to make route redirect to login if user is not loggedIn in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex, vue-router

What is the problem in guard route the condition `if(!store.getters.loggedIn)` is always return false. If no token I can to go very routes. can anyone tell me the solution plz .
my expectation is want to make guard route when user is not login and there is not token from api it will redirect to login page and if user is not loggin the user can only go to login page.

in store.js

```js
import http from '@/axiosAPI/axios.js';
import router from '@/route/index';

const auth = {
namespaced: true,
state:{
    Users: [],
    Errors: [],
    Success:"",
    Loginerror:"",
    Token: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null,
},
getters:{
    loggedIn(state){
        return state.Token !== null;
    }
},
mutations:{  
    LOGIN_ERROR(state,erro){
        state.Loginerror = erro;
    },
    AUTH(state,token){
        state.Token = token;
    },
    UNAUTH(state){
        state.Token = null;
    }
},
actions:{
    loginUser({commit}, formData){
        http.post("/login",formData).then((response)=>{
            if(response.data.status === 'success'){
                //set token
                const token = response.data.token;
                localStorage.setItem('access_token',token);
                localStorage.setItem('user',response.data.user);
                commit('AUTH',token); 
                router.push({name:'Dashboard'});
                router.go();
            }else{
                commit("LOGIN_ERROR",response.data.message);
            }
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            if(error){
                commit('UNAUTH');
                localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
                localStorage.removeItem('user');
                commit("GET_ERRORS",error.response.data.errors);
            }
        });
    },
    logoutUser({commit}){
        http.post("/auth/logout").then((response)=>{
            if(response.data.status === "success"){
                commit('UNAUTH');
                localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
                localStorage.removeItem('user');
                router.push({name:'Login'});
                window.location.reload();
            }else{
                commit("LOGIN_ERROR",response.data.message);
            }
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            if(error){
                commit("GET_ERRORS",error.response.data.errors);
            }
        });
    },
    deleteUsers({commit},userID){
        http.delete("/auth/delete/"+userID).then((response)=>{
            if(response.data.status === 'success'){
                commit("SUCCESS",response);
                router.go(); //to reload page
            }
            else if(response.data.status ==='fail'){
                commit("GET_ERRORS",response.data.message);
            }
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error.response);
        });
    }
},
}
export default auth
```

in route.js

Even if no token i can go to every route and the condition in guard route is always return false

```js
 import route from '@/route/index.js';
    import store from '@/store/modules/auth.js';

    route.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {    
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
    if(requiresAuth){
        if(!store.getters.loggedIn){ //i think the problem is here 
            next({name: 'Login'}); 
        }else{
            next();
        }
    }else{ 
        next();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can check if a user is logged in is to check directly whether there is a token in localStorage.

```
route.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')

  //if not logged in, redirect to Login page
  if (!token) next ({ name: 'Login' });

  //else continue
  else next();
});
```